# linux lamp require files

Tags: php, linux, include, require

Not long ago I started using linux as OS principal. But I have a problem to include files.
When I try include a file which in turn includes a third file, I end up getting a error: "**failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/...**"

For example, my files are distributed in this way:

[image]

and code of the 3 files is:

**primero.php**

> require_once '../B/c/segundo.php';

**segundo.php**

> require_once '../d/tercero.php';

**tercero.php**

> echo 'success';

Error:
[image: Error]

can someone explain to me what happens? this in windows works. and the truth is I would avoid using "dirname(**FILE**)"

PD: sorry, I can't post images

Comment: can you please attach the files in the question> I have some issue opening them from the URL and it is a good practice to have the files inline. What is the problem? why you can not post the images?

Comment: I can't post pictures because my reputation is below 10. I'm new.
can see links now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using relative path, sometime is painful. Therefore what I start doing is creating a `settings.inc.php` file which I keep my important paths. For instance:

try this:
settings.inc.php

```
<?php
define("ROOT_PATH" , dirname(__FILE__) . "/");
define("CLASS_PATH", ROOT_PATH . "class/");
?>
```

Then, I require the settings file in the `header.php` (so I can have it on every page)

```
require_once("settings.inc.php");
```

And I use it like

```
require_once(ROOT_PATH . 'B/c/segundo.php');
```

And

```
require_once(ROOT_PATH . 'd/tercero.php');
```

Comment: Thanks. It is an interesting solution. **But why does it work on wamp and not in lamp?**

Comment: xampp hide error by default and LAMP doesn't. What I mean, on XAMP the value of `display_errors` is `0`  and  `1` in LAMP `error_reporting(E_ALL);` `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` but if you check the error log I am 100% sure you will see the error. (c:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log)

Comment: No, do not mean to the error_reporting. I mean if I run primero.php in wamp, this will include the files without problems (this works). While in lamp, gives me error...  why?

Comment: To be honest with you, I never saw XAMPP treating differently relative paths than LAMP. I might have to check your code to see it with my own eyes. I will setup a Windows machine to check code out and let you know.

Comment: Got the files. It might take a while. I have to get a Windows installation and install it with Virtualbox. I haven't run a Windows machine for a few years :-S Thank you for sharing your code

Answer (score 0):

Using [__DIR__](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) in front of require makes the required path relative to the file in which it is defined. For example:

```
  require_once __DIR__.'/../d/tercero.php';
```